# If I want to make a statement that everything is as you said... I use 'Just like said'. is this right?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning, syntactic-analysis

This is just to make a statement. A shortened one but does it completely justify or give a picture that this is what i meant ' just as you said or just like you said'.

Comment: "As you said." or, "you were spot on." convey your message. The sentence needs the subject though or it is just a fragment. "Spot On" could be used if it is understood what you are referring to, but that requires other background conversation to establish what you are talking about.

Comment: I have come across this line from a company which says that they deliver what they promise. But I think this is something very awkward to say.

Comment: You wouldn't say "Just like said", as in your title. You would say "Just like **you** said", as in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Correct.
Affirmative.
Just so.
Exactly.
Precisely.